# How to create a Line Graph from the results of a For Loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, naivebayes

I am using the following code in Python to generate results from a Naive Bayes classification problem on the Iris dataset. From using this code, I can successfully generate the test size and accuracy, however when I try to plot this output on a line graph, I'm unable to. What am I missing when trying to plot the test sizes and their accuracies?

```
#NaiveBayes

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

irisX = iris_df.loc[:, iris_df.columns != 'species'].values
irisy = iris_df.loc[:, iris_df.columns == 'species'].values.ravel()


gnb = GaussianNB()
acc=[]

for j in range(0, 20):
    for i in range(10): 
        ts=0.6+(j*0.01)
        irisX, irisy = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(irisX, irisy, test_size=ts, random_state=None)
        gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
        a = accuracy_score(y_test, gnb.predict(X_test))
        acc += [a]
    print(f"test size={ts:.2f} acc={np.array(acc).mean():.3f}")
    
X_ = [ts]
Y_ = [np.array(acc).mean()]

plt.plot(X_, Y_)
plt.title('Naive Bayes Performance Plot')
plt.xlabel('Test Size')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To plot a line graph we need to have arrays of values not just a single value. if we have single value we get only one point on graph but to get line graph we need array of values. but in your code X_ is list of ts where ts is just a single value instead of array also Y_ is also a single value. so to plot line graph we need arrays which we get by moving X_ and Y_ inside loop as shown below.

```
gnb = GaussianNB()
acc=[]
X_ = []
Y_ = []

for j in range(0, 20):
    for i in range(10): 
        ts=0.6+(j*0.01)
        irisX, irisy = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(irisX, irisy, 
test_size=ts, random_state=None)
        gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
        a = accuracy_score(y_test, gnb.predict(X_test))
        acc += [a]
        X_.append(ts)
        Y_.append(np.array(acc).mean())
        print(f"test size={ts:.2f} acc={np.array(acc).mean():.3f}")
plt.plot(X_, Y_)
plt.title('Naive Bayes Performance Plot')
plt.xlabel('Test Size')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.show()
```

Output is shown below:
[image]

Comment: consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helps you.